# How to call generic method with stronger constraint?

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

```
namespace Test
{
    #region Not my code
    public interface IAdditional
    {
    }
    public interface ISome
    {
        ISomeOther<T> GetSomeother<T>() where T : class;
    }
    public interface ISomeOther<T> where T : class
    {
        void DoFoo(T obj);
    }
    public class AnotherClass<T> where T : class
    {
    }
    public static class StaticClass
    {
        public static void DoBar<T>(AnotherClass<T> anotherClass, T obj) where T : class, IAdditional
        {
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region MyCode
    public class SomeOtherImp<T> : ISomeOther<T> where T : class, IAdditional //Have to add IAdditional constraint to call StaticClass.DoBar
    {
        private AnotherClass<T> _anotherClass;
        public void DoFoo(T obj)
        {
            StaticClass.DoBar<T>(_anotherClass, obj); //I do need to call StaticClass.DoBar here....
        }
    }
    public class ISomeImp : ISome
    {
        public ISomeOther<T> GetSomeother<T>() where T : class
        {
            return new SomeOtherImp<T>(); //Can't do this no IAdditional constraint on T
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

I was forced to add `IAdditional` to `SomeOtherImp` to be able to call `StaticClass.DoBar`.

And now I can't implement `ISome` with `SomeOtherImp<T>`.

Comment: How to call SomeStaticClass.Create<T> from ISome.Get() implemented method.

Comment: Can you provide the code of `ISomeInterface`? You show us `ISome` only.

Comment: Sorry guys i completely failed in writing sample code for my problem, here is the new edited sample code

Comment: Don't make a new one, just fix this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to be able to call the Get method? If you can edit the interface ISome, try this:

```
public interface ISome
{
    T Get<T>() where T:class, ISomeInterface
}
```

...otherwise you're going to have to use reflection:

```
public class Foo : ISome
{
    public T Get<T>() where T:class
    {
        if (!typeof(ISomeInterface).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))) throw new Exception();
        return (T)typeof(SomeStaticClass).GetMethod("Create").MakeGenericMethod(new [] {typeof(T)}).Invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: Heh I was hoping this can be done without reflection with some inheritance magic.. looks like not.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do this

```
public class Foo : ISome
{
    public T Get<T>() where T : class
    {
        return SomeStaticClass.Create<ISomeInterface>() as T; 
    }
}
```

If it returns null, you passed in a type that was not an ISomeInterface.

Comment: Looks like I have oversimplified my code actualy Get<T>() returns IBar<T> I should edit the question )

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to implement factory design pattern. Take a look at the following piece of code. I removed the interface from restrictions of SomeClass. It compiles and will work. In my opinion ISome and its implementation Foo class are obsolete.

```
public static class SomeStaticClass
{
    public static T Create<T>() where T:class
    {
        //Replace with actual construction of T
        return (T)(new object());
    }
}

public interface ISome
{
    T Get<T>() where T : class;
}

public class Foo : ISome
{
    public T Get<T>() where T:class
    {
        return SomeStaticClass.Create<T>(); 
    }
}
```